# Nested if/else, switches or something more efficient for RPG combat?

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, nested-statement

I'm developing a turn based RPG in java for android phones and I'm currently trying to figure out how to handle attacks that have extra variables beyond damage.  For example, I would like to have fire attacks do an extra 10% damage  when the target has a burn effect.  I'm a bit unsure how to go about doing this in an efficient way and one that allows for future additions to my status/attack system.

So here are my thoughts on how I can do this:

1. A series of if/else statements or switch's

   ```
   switch (status) {
   case burned:
       if (type == fire) {
           damage = damage * 1.1;
       }
       break;
   case frozen:
       if (type == ice) {
           damage = damage * 2;
       }
       break;
   }
   ```

   I could also use nested switches if I have many possible results for each status.
2. Use an two dimensional array with the `x` values being statuses and the `y` values being attacks or types.  When you check the `[x][y]` it returns a numerical value for the change that will occur in attack.

   ```
         Burned   Frozen

   Fire  [1.1]    [1]

   Ice   [1]      [2]
   ```

While both of these seem fine for now, I'm unsure if it will work for the future.  Right now, I can certainly use combinations that change the damage amount, but what about attacks that have non-numerical effects where I can't simply return a value and multiply my damage by that value?

Would it be possible to generate some sort of code that represents a situation like:

```
burned = 1 in first position, frozen = 2
fire attack = f in 2nd position, ice = i
damage mod is in the 3rd position
```

so a fire attack on a burned enemy would be `1-f-1.1`.

Comment: `switch` won't work that way in the java level you must use for Android apps (must be an int, cant be a string, although you could set a static variable to a value and use that).

Comment: @willmer : Your question is a little to vague. I understand what you're asking but it's more related to game development methodology and would be better suited to a game developer site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try to use polymorphism.

## For the switches/if-elses

Create an interface that represents attacks, and let it declare a single method:

```
public interface Attack {
    double doAttack(double baseDamage);
}
```

Then create classes that implement this interface:

```
public class FireAttack implements Attack {
    double doAttack(double baseDamage){
        return 1.1 * baseDamage;
    }
}

public class IceAttack implements Attack {
    double doAttack(double baseDamage){
        return 2 * baseDamage;
    }
}
```

Then instead of using switch statements in your code, do something like this:

```
public class Player {
    private Attack mAttack;

    // Somewhere in your code, you setup something like
    void setFireWeapon(){
        mAttack = new FireAttack();
    }

    // This is where the attack is taken care of
    double inflictDamage() {
        return mAttack.doAttack();
    }
}
```

What this allows you to do is to implement any new type of attack you may wish in the future, and simply assign `Attack mAttack` with this new implementation of interface `Attack`.  This is a trivial exemple, you could do some stuff much more powerfull than `baseDamage * aDouble` if you wish.

## For the status (burned/frozen)

There are many ways you could implement states like frozen.  First you could use the same pattern I explained above.

On top of having a `Attack mAttack` member, you could also add similar logic with a `HealthStatus mHealthStatus` or whatever name you prefer.  Then the call to `inflictDamage()` would redirect the `mAttack` object to the `mHealthStatus` object.

Then the `HealthStatus` class would again be an interface,

```
public interface HealthStatus {
    double considerAttack(Attack anAttack);
}
```

which would have implementations of various states:

```
public class NormalStatus implements HealthStatus{
    double considerAttack(Attack anAttack){
        return anAttack.doAttack(); // No change here
    }
}

public class FrozenStatus implements HealthStatus{
    double considerAttack(Attack anAttack){
        return 0; // Can't attack when froxen
    }
}

public class BurnedStatus implements HealthStatus{
    double considerAttack(Attack anAttack){
        return anAttack.doAttack() * 2.0; // Get berserk when on fire!
    }
}
```

You could also use the other patterns.  I recommend you look at Design Patterns, which solve problems like the one you are facing.

- See State pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern
- See Strategy pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern
- See Visitor pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

AntonieG is on the right track.  The general solution to this problem is to use the Strategy Design pattern.

**Strategy**

*Motivation*

There are common situations when classes differ only in their behavior. For this cases is a good idea to isolate the algorithms in separate classes in order to have the ability to select different algorithms at runtime.

*Intent*

Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it.

*Implementation*

[image: Strategy Pattern Impl]
http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html

Also take a look at the following links.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/11/22/applying-strategy-pattern-instead-of-using-switch-statements.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking seems too linear. Use Object Oriented principles to design your game. Create classes for your attacks that extend the generic attack.

```
public abstract class Attack{
    protected String attackName;
    protected Double damage;

    public Attack(){
        attackName = "Standard";
        damage = 1.0;
    }

    public Double getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }

    public String getAttackName(){
        return attackName;
    }
}
```

Then extend:

```
public class FireStorm extends Attack{
    public FireStorm(String attackName, Double damage){
        this.attackName = attackName;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getDamage(Enemy target){
        if(target.hasBurnEffect()){
            damage *= 2.0;
        } else {
            damage = super.getDamage();
        }

        return damage;
    }
}
```

I don't really know much about the scope of things in your game, so I can't make it too much more descriptive. But if you're wanting to make your game flexible and extendable as you suggest, then you will want to use inheritance and other principles of object oriented programming.

Comment: Does this mean that for every attack I have in the game, I would be coding it in as a new subclass of Attack?  I currently have a class called Attack with variable such as Name, Description, Power, and Speed. I have a SQLite database that searches for the attack by name and returns the values corresponding to those variables.  Then within the class I call Attack.doAttack(enemyType type) which checks the type (ie fire vs water) and returns the damage.

Rather than having a class for each move, I wanted to reuse the same template for my moves and insert the values.  Is that an inefficient way?